# Android MVP: which layer should store context variable

Tags: android, mvp

I find myself where i need to play a sound file when user clicks a button on a view.

MediaPlayer requires a context to be created.

What is the best way to put MediaPlayer initialization code?

Should I pass a context into a presenter method and play it there?

Or is it ok to just play on the view.

Comment: An activity is a Context

Comment: you should write that inside activity. Otherwise presenter doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Context` is a part of Android `View` Layer in MVP, so `Presenter` must not have any idea about it and you should not pass it to `presenter`.

You have to add a methods to your `View` interface and implement it inside your android view components (i.e. `Activity` or `Fragment`) and use them to do an action in `View` layer as playing a sound.

`Presenter` must ask for the UI event and `View` must handle it!

Here is a **MVP** sample using **Dagger**, **RxJava** and **Retrofit**, which might help you to learn more about MVP in Android:

https://github.com/mmirhoseini/marvel

Comment: I like this answer because it is short and answers my question. I will basically keep the MediaPlayer/MediaRecorder logic inside view.

Answer (score 7):

I often put business logic code in **Model Layer** (don't make confusion with model in database). I often rename as `XManager` for avoiding confusion (such as `ProductManager`, `MediaManager` ...) so presenter class just uses for keeping workflow.

The rule of thumb is no or at least limit **import android package** in presenter class. This best practice supports you easier in testing presenter class because presenter now is just a plain java class, so we don't need android framework for testing those things.

For example here is my mvp workflow.

**View class**: This is a place you store all your view such as button, textview ... and you set all listeners for those view components on this layer. Also on this View, you define a Listener class for presenter implements later. Your view components will call methods on this listener class.

```
class ViewImpl implements View {
   Button playButton;
   ViewListener listener;

   public ViewImpl(ViewListener listener) {
     // find all view

     this.listener = listener;

     playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       listener.playSong();
     });
   }

   public interface ViewListener {
     playSong();
   }
}
```

**Presenter class:** This is where you store view and model inside for calling later. Also presenter class will implement ViewListener interface has defined above. Main point of presenter is control logic workflow.

```
class PresenterImpl extends Presenter implements ViewListener {
    private View view;
    private MediaManager mediaManager;

    public PresenterImpl(View, MediaManager manager) {
       this.view = view;
       this.manager = manager;
    }

    @Override
    public void playSong() {
       mediaManager.playMedia();
    }
}
```

**Manager class:** Here is the core business logic code.  Maybe one presenter will have many managers (depend on how complicate the view is). Often we get `Context` class through some injection framework such as `Dagger`.

```
Class MediaManagerImpl extends MediaManager {
   // using Dagger for injection context if you want
   @Inject
   private Context context;
   private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

   // dagger solution
   public MediaPlayerManagerImpl() {
     this.mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(context);
   }

   // no dagger solution
   public MediaPlayerManagerImpl(Context context) {
     this.context = context;
     this.mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(context);
   }

   public void playMedia() {
     mediaPlayer.play();
   }

   public void stopMedia() {
      mediaPlayer.stop();
   }
}
```

**Finally:** Put those thing together in Activities, Fragments ... Here is the place you initialize view, manager and assign all to presenter.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

   Presenter presenter;

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();

      IView view = new ViewImpl();
      MediaManager manager = new   MediaManagerImpl(this.getApplicationContext());
      // or this. if you use Dagger
      MediaManager manager = new   MediaManagerImpl();
      presenter = new PresenterImpl(view, manager);
   }   

   @Override
   public void onStop() {
     super.onStop();
     presenter.onStop();
   }
}
```

You see that each presenter, model, view is wrapped by one interface. Those components will called through interface. This design will make your code more robust and easier for modifying later.

This is such a long post for answering your question. I think this is suitable because everyone has their own MVP implementation (core flow is same, but minorities are different). So I present here a workflow I often use in work. Hoping you see this useful :)

Comment: I need to use context in my model class to get local strings(context.getString(R.string...), but i often hear, business logic should only contain POJO and should not contain any android specific classes. However, i haven't found any solution other than passing context to model as a parameter. Does MVVM solve this issue where you need some context resources?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a generic Context you can extend Application, declare a static context variable and after you can get this Context into your presenter.

Comment: Standard warning: Do not place Android context classes in static fields; this is a memory leak (and also breaks Instant Run)